# Alert! /dev/sda5 does not exist. Dropping to a shell

Tags: grub2, initramfs

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop but when I start it's shown this error

```
ALERT! /dev/sda5 does not exist. Dropping to a shell

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu v1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6) built-in shell (ash)
Enter help for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I tried to fix following some steps like to restore grub and mount the correct 'section' but I have the same problem.

I also reinstalled the operational system but nothing changes.